# what is endpoint path to retrieve file manager directory for each domain in cpanel

Tags: python, web-scraping, post, request, cpanel

i made a python script to get file manager directory of each all domains exist on my cpanel with request post to get each directory in json response.but doesnt work with me

maybe send request post to 'Document Root' to get the file manager directory tbh idk exactly

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.